# Camel - CXF Endpoint - JMS Request-Reply model

Tags: jms, cxf, apache-camel

I have CXF endpoint. I have dedicated route defined for each operation and routing the request to appropriate routes using header.operation name with reciepient list.
For couple operations(routes), I have post request to JMS endpoint which gets processed by another application and response is recieved in another queue. I have to read response message and transform the message. My requesting thread(webservice call) would be waiting for the transformed message.
Currently after posting request, currently I have written my own processor which use spring jms template to read message. I came across few examples such as split routes but not sure how it will work for overall synchronous communication which has in between JMS communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a JMX Request/Reply example here:

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="setResponseProcessor" class="org.apache.camel.itest.jetty.SetResponseProcessor"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf://serverBean"/>
        <to uri="jms:responseQueue"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:responseQueue"/>
        <process ref="setResponseProcessor"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: This example looks like it sends and reads from same queue. In my case, I would dropping message to request queue and waiting on response queue with correlation id.

Comment: Above answer will work with additional ReplyTO parameter meter being set to responseQueue. Route 2 message will got to replyTo queue and original requester thread will read from ReplyTo queue. e.g. '<camel:to uri="amq:authRequestQueue?replyTo=authResponseQueue?selector=JMSCorrelationID=${header.JMSCorrelationID}" pattern="InOut" />'